# How to make materialized view update immediately (or is there a manual refresh command) in Cassandra?

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I can only use CQL (i.e., I can set consistency to `ALL` and then my key space setup is `WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1}`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately materialized views are inherently broken.  The only way to rebuild/refresh a view is to recreate it:

ref: https://www.mail-archive.com/user@cassandra.apache.org/msg54073.html